Certain outputs not showing in-line in Rmarkdown
Recently, certain outputs (esp. modelsummary and ggplot) haven't been displaying in-line after RMarkdown chunks. They either don't show, or show in the viewer pane. However, some outputs, such as head() etc. do display in-line.
I've tried all the settings I know about this - the global RMarkdown settings, the gear icon on the toolbar. Does anyone know what might be causing this? This is only a recent issue, so might be caused by an RStudio update.
Thanks
